# Hidden input type="file" submit on change

Tags: html, forms

I need a *file upload button* that does **not** look like the default "select file"-button.

Therefor I have a styled `<button>` and a **hidden** `input[type="file"]`

It appears however, that **everytime I click on the `<button>` the parent `<form>` gets submitted** and I do not understand why. There is no javascript triggering the form to submit. It **submits while the filepicker-dialog is open** so the `POST` request **has no file sent** at all.

I want it to **submit** the form but only **after I selected a file** (file-input has **changed**)

```
<form action="/upload.php" method="post" name="ta_file_upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="tableUpload1" name="files[]" style="visibility:hidden;" onchange="alert();" /> <!-- no alert is fired! -->
    <button class="btn btn-dark table-button table-button-upload" onclick="document.getElementById('tableUpload1').click()" title="Upload">UploadButton</button>
</form>
```

The `alert();` is for testing purposes - it does not get triggered: no alert.

The error is not related to a specific browser (tested in chrome + firefox)

Comment: Default type of a `button` is submit, change type to button to prevent submitting the form

Comment: I did not know that! You are right, now it's working!